# How do I know when Mongoose addToSet actually adds something?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a database which includes projects, and each project has an array of links. My express.js code when adding links is as such:

```
router.get('/links/add', function(req, res){
    Project.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id: req.query.pid},
        {$addToSet: {links: {url: req.query.url , title: req.query.title} }}, 
        {safe: true, upsert: true, new:true},
        function(err, project) {
            if(err) {
                //do stuff
            } else {
                //Something was added to set!
            }
        }
   );
});
```

It works perfectly fine and doesn't add duplicates, but I need to know when something is actually updated. Now, you can see I have enabled the `new:true` option which returns the new document, so I could just remove that and see if the link exists in the old version, but is there a way to do it with the flag enabled?

It seems like a basic function but I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Do you want to view the new updated information?  Or are you trying to determine if something was updated?  Couldn't you just fire an event in the else statement?

Comment: I want to see if something was updated. I can already see the "updated" document (read: the document's state after the query) with the `new:true` flag , I just don't see a way of figuring out if something was actually added. Code enters the else block even if nothing was added, it's not considered an error by mongoose.

Comment: Hmmm, I think the best way would be to do a find before the find and update.  Then compare the find value to the value that you intend to update it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are adding to a set, we will find the set, then check if our update value is in the set.  If it is we can end the function, otherwise we can update while keeping knowledge of what was updated.  (This is the gist, there may be an error or two since I can't test it myself).

```
router.get('/links/add', function(req, res){
    var updating = false;

    Project.find({_id: req.query.pid}, function(err, project) {
      if(err) {
        // handle error
      } else {
        // Check if found project contains what we mean to update.  
        // If it does already (nothing is changing) leave updating as false
        // and we exit.

        // Otherwise keep reference to what is being updated, set updating to
        // true, and after we finish updating you have reference to what changed
      }
    }
    if(updating) {
      Project.findOneAndUpdate(
          {_id: req.query.pid},
          {$addToSet: {links: {url: req.query.url , title: req.query.title} }}, 
          {safe: true, upsert: true, new:true},
          function(err, project) {
              if(err) {
                  //do stuff
              } else {
                  //Something was added to set!
              }
          }
      );
   }
});
```

Comment: Since I already know a way to do it with 1 query (disabling the `new` flag) I wanted to focus on finding a way to make mongoose return something useful to me through the update itself, instead of having to do 2 queries. I will accept this nonetheless if no such solution shows up.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.  I don't know of a way to do it in that manner though.